# Why do the rounded corners of a card view dissapear when using Material transitions?

Tags: android, material-design, rounded-corners, android-transitions, cardview

I use Material transitions when switching between fragments, in this case a SharedZAxisTransition, but my problem is that if an image is wrapped inside a cardview, the corners of that cardview somehow dissapear as soon as the transition starts.  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGwoT.jpg)

I don't know why that is happening, i've been struggeling with this for a few days. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution. I just needed to set a background color on the root layout and add transitionGroup="true" to the cardview, now it works.